# Swift objects won't update after delegate called

Tags: ios, swift, variables, object, delegates

I want a stepper and label to reset to zero after my variable in another class is also reset.  The variables reset but the stepper and label do not even after using a delegate.

View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CircleViewDelegate {

var colors = CircleView()

@IBOutlet weak var circleView1: CircleView!
@IBOutlet weak var redStepper: UIStepper!

@IBOutlet weak var redValue: UILabel!

@IBAction func stepperChange(sender: UIStepper)
{
    circleView1.redd1 = Int(redStepper.value);
    redValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
}

    func updateRedStepperValue(value: Double) {
    redStepper.value = value
    redValue.text = Int(colors.redd1.value).description;
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    colors.delegate = self
} 
}
```

CircleView:

```
protocol CircleViewDelegate
{
    func updateRedStepperValue(value: Double)
    func updateGreenStepperValue(value: Double)
    func updateBlueStepperValue(value: Double)
}

class CircleView: UIView
{

var delegate: CircleViewDelegate?
    var redd1 = 0

func updateValues()
{
    if(redd1==Int(red1))
    {
        redd1=0;
        delegate?.updateRedStepperValue(0.0)//
    }
}
}
```

Comment: are your delegate called in main / gui thread ?

Comment: Is Delegate really called? Can you just print out the value of it?

Comment: you were right. I put print in one delegate function and nothing printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your making a brand new instance of your CircleView.

```
let cycle = CircleView()
```

You need to set your delegate to your current working instance.

To do so, you should replace your assignment in your viewDidLoad with the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate
        if let viewControllers = app.window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers {
            viewControllers.forEach { vc in
                if let cont = vc as? CircleView {
                    cont.delegate = self
                }
            }
        }
}
```

[Here's an article with project files.](https://www.codebeaulieu.com/72/Delegation-between-two-container-views)

Comment: I gave it a try but same problem

Comment: In the link I've provided you'll find a simple project I made that you can compare your code to.